# Photoshop showing background of masked objects imported from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I'm having a new problem I haven't experienced before. After designing a poster in Illustrator, I import it into Photoshop to flatten/downsave. In my original ai file, I have embedded psd files with masked areas. After opening in Photoshop, the masked area shows faintly. [image: masked area visible]

In the past, I've used this image before in the same way without issues. Is there a workaround or way to fix it without going back to the original .psd file and deleting the background instead of masking it?

Comment: Is it an opacity mask or clipping mask in Illustrator? If opacity mask.. is the black 100%CMYK??

Comment: I open a pic in Photoshop, used a layer mask to "get rid" of background, and saved as PSD. Then when I need it, I drag into Illustrator and embed. Then I need to downsave/flatten the .ai file, so I open it in PS to flatten and save. In the original .psd and .ai files, the background is not visible, but when I open the .ai in PS, the background is visible.

Comment: Is the layer mask in Photoshop 100% black? It somewhat appears that it may be 98% or 99% black.

Comment: It is 100% black. I've used this file in the same way before and not had this issue. I got a new computer at work recently and my Adobe programs are glitching and running slower than before, so I'm hoping that is the issue. I'm contacting IT.